# Android Studio appcompat drawable-hdpi-v4 resources not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

```
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
...\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png
(The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
```

It is happenning randomly, one of each two times the project is built.
And the missed file is not only `abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png`, but always is a drawable resource used in AppCompat styles.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

I have also tried with older SDK versions & older appcompat library version cause a possible bug in new releases, but the error keeps showing up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing resource `drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_scrubber_control_to_pressed_mtrl_005.png` is from v4

So, add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

Add the support design library as well

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

Comment: I also have this error :

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/et_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08006b.

i add this dependency but same error please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean the project?
1. Build -> Clean project
2. Build -> Rebuild project